# First elements of list of list Prolog

Tags: prolog

I m studying Prolog and i see this code

```
foo([],[]).
foo([[A,_ ]|L], [A|P]) :-foo(L ,P).
```

The result say that this code take N element of list of list, 
Ad example if we give this query:

```
?foo([[car],[house],[man]],X)
X= [c,h,m]
```

At first read i see that something wrong. 
For me this code take the tail of list of list and the rest of first element of the list , so for me first expansion will be  (trace)

```
foo([[house],[man]], ar)
foo([[man]], ouse)
foo([], an)
false.
```

I try to compile with swi-prolog and give this trace:

```
[trace]  ?- trace,foo([[car],[house],[man]],X).
Call: (9) foo([[car], [house], [man]], _1016) ? creep
Fail: (9) foo([[car], [house], [man]], _1016) ? creep
false.
```

What are I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Obtaining the first elements

The pattern `[A, _]` in your clause is wrong, or at at least *not generic enough*. `[A, _]` unifies with a list that contains *exactly two* elements, but this will thus fail for lists with more than two elements, or with one elements, like you found out.

You need to use the `[A|_]` pattern: indeed a list where the head is `A`, and we are not interested in the rest (tail). like:

```
foo([],[]).
foo([[A|_]|L], [A|P]) :- foo(L, P).
```

That being said, you can simplify this, by implementing a predicate that takes the head of a list:

```
head([H|_], H).
```

and then make use of [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
foo(A, B) :-
    maplist(head, A, B).
```

`maplist` will thus call `head` like `head(Ai, Bi)`, with `Ai` and `Bi` elements of `A` and `B` respectively.

## Obtaining a substring with the first character

but based on the sample output, this is not what you want: you also want to obtain the first "character" of the atom, we can do that by using [**`string_chars/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=string_chars/2):

```
head_first([A|_], C) :-
    string_chars(A, [C|_]).
```

and then define `foo/2` again with [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
foo(A, B) :-
    maplist(head_first, A, B).
```

we then obtain:

```
?- foo([[car],[house],[man]], X).
X = [c, h, m].
```

Comment: maybe this my question will do stupid.. [A|P] in the foo/2  don't take a first list (in list of list) and give the tail P from foot(L,P). Because i understand well [[A|_]|L], but [A|P] i have some doubts. By the way, always clear. Sorry for my more question on prolog, i m studying the subject.

Comment: With `[A|P]` we are at that moment *constructing* (well given we read in in that direction) a list, so `A` is the *first element* of the result, and `P` the tail (remaining list). You actually wrote the `[A|P]` part yourself in your question.

Comment: "constructing "  you mean a a variable part? (X = [c, h, m]). Because for my first look on the code I thought that this part is refers to list of the list (first element in the query), but i m wrong sure( because is second element)

Comment: @theantomc: yes, here we are constructing the `X = [c, h, m]` part.